# Multiple row input in asp.net for editing database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

From time to time, I need to create an input control which allows multiple rows of input, the type of input and number of columns could be different in each case but typically it would be represent a database table being edited, so it should also be possible to store an id value within each row. It should also be possible for the user to add new rows to the input if they have more data to input.

I have tried a couple of approaches to this but they are all very long winded for what seems like such an obvious and common scenario. I'm thinking that there must be a simple way to do this that I have missed.

The way that I usually solve this is by using a list view, enter all of the input controls required within the item template and use a html table for formatting, with each item being a row of the table. If there is existing data to be edited, I would load the data from the database, add a blank object to the results and bind it to the list view. If there is no existing data, I would create a collection with a blank record in it and bind it to the list view. I add a button for adding a new row. When clicked, this button retrieves all of the existing data from the list view by iterating all of the listview items and populating the data into a collection, which I would then add a blank object to and rebind the listview with the results. When saving, I would retrieve the results by iterating the listview items again and using a hidden field within each row to store the record id. This would determine whether a new record was added or an existing record was edited.

This approach works for me but I'm sure there must be simpler ways to achieve this. Looking forward to seeing how other people solve this.

Comment: Why don't u simple bind data to an editable GridView? Almost everything can be declared in ASPX markup of the page and everything (Add, Edit, Delete, Update) is handled automatically.

Comment: This sounds like the answer I was looking for. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

For web forms, use a GridView.  You can set its properties to allow editing, deleting, new rows, sorting, and paging.

Check out the MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) that shows how to use it.  If you bind a datasource to it, it will figure out the columns and adjust dynamically then, or you can predefine the columns you want for more customability.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about bulk insert/update. You could use XML insertion/updation for this purpose. Get all the data to a `DataSet ds` variable. Then use `ds.GetXml()` method to convert the dataset to XML string. Pass this to an XML parameter into SQL server which has the datatype 'XML'

```
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
    SELECT
        V.VOI.value('(.)[1]', 'int')
    FROM
        @Input.nodes('/DATASETNAME/DATATABLENAME/') V(VOI)
```

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146789/2281515) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic table with Add, View,Edit and delete operations on each data.

I would suggest using DataTable Jquery component. there are tons of examples on Data operations, and you can plug this with any Server technology including ASP.net

http://editor.datatables.net/